# Can a team change the F1 radio notification sound to another sound?

Tags: formula-1

Basically, when an engineer wants to talk to the driver, we will hear the [F1 radio notification sound](https://youtu.be/hGWtVxwDZxw). Can a team change the sound to a new one, or is it compulsory to use the sound in order to talk to each other?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the notification sound is part of the actual radio message. As far as I'm aware, it's part of the TV coverage, played to draw the viewers' attention to the incoming message (and also to alert the commentators so they don't talk over it). So it's not something the teams have control over.